# how to detect if registry key has error C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have seen a lot of software that show that which registry has error. I just want to know what exactly they look for ? I mean i know how to get value of registry key but how do I decide whether that value is correct or not ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Most software like this looks for enteries that exist in a location that most of the time should be referenced in another location.  You should not modify the registry unless you understand how the registery works and it sounds like you don't.

Comment: Registry values don't have "errors." The value that each registry value needs is *solely* dependent on the software that is reading it.

Comment: As a rule, you should only modify registry entries your application is responsible for: a "dirty" registry will only have a very marginal effect on performances on modern versions of windows, so a registry cleaner is more likiely to break something than to make your computer run faster.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: If registry dont have errors then how do registry cleaning software works, con you guide me on this

Comment: @Ramhound: I just want to write a registry cleaning software, so thats my question how to start on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link which provides full information about how to write a registry cleaner software and wat are the things to be done.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301890/ScanX-Creating-a-Registry-Cleaner

Comment: @Iridium: Why do you think that its a bad idea?

Comment: As others have mentioned, there is not a significant overhead to having registry entries related to files that are no longer present on the system so it's trying to solve a problem that doesn't really exist. It's also seems to be quite a blunt instrument, and could find strings that look like file paths but aren't, and so get from the registry, potentially breaking legitimate applications. There are also some circumstances where a registry entry may be a file that could legitimately not exist (e.g. on located a drive not currently available). So, as I said, seems like a very bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/features) lists these items as features for their cleaner:

> Advanced features to remove unused and old entries, including File
>   Extensions, ActiveX Controls, ClassIDs, ProgIDs, Uninstallers, Shared
>   DLLs, Fonts, Help Files, Application Paths, Icons, Invalid Shortcuts
>   and more...

You can find these bottlenecks by reading the manual.